# Recommend that VS Recommend to

Tags: verbs, infinitives

I`ve been taught for years that the verb **recommend** is one of those verbs of advice that cannot be followed by the more usual pattern of object + infinitive but has to be followed by a that-clause with should + infinitive or with past, present or subjunctive form verbs. Recently, however, I found an entry in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary which states that the object + infinitive pattern is indeed possible with the **recommend** verb. Am I missing something here?

Below I enclose the link to the entry:

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary: recommend](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend)

Comment: So we know which entry you are referring to, you need to quote it after your link.

Comment: I suggest that you include the sentence(s) you want to get information about in your question's body.

Comment: In the link mentioned, I cannot find any examples of *recommend + to-infinitive*. Either the OP misread the entry, or the web page has been updated; this is an example of why it is important to quote sources rather than merely link to them.

Answer (score 1):

From your link:

> We'd recommend you to book your flight early.

Maybe that's a British English thing.  It's sounds very odd to this American.

In the US, we'd say "We'd recommend [that] you book your flight early."

No "to".

Answer (score 0):

*Michael Swan* — *Practical English Usage*, lists some of the verbs which can be used with the **object + infinitive** structure.
These are: *advise, allow, ask, bear, beg, cause, command, compel, encourage, expect, forbid, force, get, hate, help, instruct, instruct, intend, invite, leave, like, love, mean, need, oblige, order, permit, persuade, prefer, **recommend**, remind, request, teach, tell, tempt, trouble, want, warn, wish.*

Some verbs cannot be followed by this structure, they need a *that* clause. For instance, **suggest**:

> *I **suggested** that she should go home.*

However, many other verbs listed above can also be followed by *that* clauses, for example, but it seems you'll have to use a dictionary for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

> **I recommend to** *infinitive*

directly dives into what you are recommending without delay by mentioning the infinitive

> **I recommend that**

introduces a clause that qualifies what you are recommending

> **I recommend to** go, now!
>   **I recommend that** we leave at the earliest possible time which is convenient, like right now!

Comment: Shouldn't it be **"I recommend we go, now!"**

Comment: That works also, there are several ways to express this.